# Create Flash module on intellij through gradle

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, apache-flex, gradlefx

The flex application module that is created through my build.gradle file in intellij is a java module and not a flash module.

```
//Define buildscript properties
buildscript {
    //Use the primary maven repo
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    //We need the gradlefx plugin to run
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'org.gradlefx', name: 'gradlefx', version: '1.4.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'gradlefx'

flexHome = System.getenv('FLEX_HOME')
type = 'swf'
srcDirs = ['./', '../web_stuff']
resourceDirs = ['/resources']
mainClass = 'Web'
output = 'Web'
playerVersion = '11.1'

//Compile using the config file, this file will be dynamically modified to easily switch between variants
additionalCompilerOptions = ['-load-config=' + """pwd""".execute().text.trim() + '/buildSrc/flex-config.xml', '-target-player=11.1']

//Define our HTML wrapper
htmlWrapper {
    source = '../html-template/index.template.html'
    title = "1.28.00"
    application = "${project.mainClass}"
    swf = "${project.mainClass}"

    file = "${project.mainClass}" + ".html"
    }
}

compileFlex.dependsOn createHtmlWrapper

//Use the primary maven repo
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

//We need these libs to compile
dependencies {
    //Our included swc files
    internal fileTree(dir: '../flex_libs', include: '*.swc')
    //Use the tomcat rsls that will be referenced at runtime
    merged fileTree(dir: System.getenv('FLEX_HOME') + '/frameworks/rsls', include: '*.swf')

    flexSDK files('../../../ApacheFlexSDK.zip')
}
```

It's a multiproject gradle application

```
rootFolder
    build.gradle
    setting.gradle
    javaApp
        build.gradle
        src
    flexApp
        build.gradle
        src
```

The compileFlex in flexApp build.gradle is called from the javaApp build.gradle. The java module is created just fine with no issues.

Comment: Try `ideafx` gradle plugin: http://doc.gradlefx.org/en/latest/ide_plugin.html#idea-intellij-plugin

Comment: I tried that but get the same error as mentioned here: (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-146954)